# How do I create a delivery model with products and amounts?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to do some sort of shop. The user gets a delivery (**delivery model**) with some products (**product model**). The user can choose the quantity of the products.

The models have a structure like so:

```
class Delivery(models.Model):
    some stuff...

class Product(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product,related_name="deliveries", blank=True, null=True)
    some stuff...
```

But now I am really confused how to solve this seemingly simple problem. Where do I specify the amount of a product in each delivery. Obviously, the amounts vary per delivery, so I can hardly specify a field with amount on the product ... I am really confused about this ... maybe someone can direct me to a helpful resource?

Answer (score 1):

I think these three models should be enough to get you stared:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    unitprice = models.IntegerField()

class Delivery(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # each delivery is for a user 

class Deliverable(models.Model):
    delivery = models.ForeignKey(Delivery, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # each deliverable item belongs to a delivery
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # each deliverable item refers to a product 
    quantity = models.IntegerField() # and how many products are to be delivered
```